# Is SVG image officialy support by flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, svg, dart

1. Is iOS and android support SVG in flutter app ?
2. Is use of SVG is safe in flutter ?

Answer (score 4):

**No flutter is not supporting yet** 2021-10-18. It is tracked in the community post below.

by the way it is safe but you have to use **flutter_svg** library

[Original issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15501?source=post_page---------------------------)

> While that issue can focus on a Flutter-specific vector drawable
> format, this issue should track SVG based support.
>
> @cbazza @deborah-ufw were also particularly interested in this.

you can use **[flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)**

Answer (score 2):

Flutter innately does not support svg as yet. However, I have used [Flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package for some of my projects(using static drawings) and have not faced any problem both performance and functionality wise.

For further reading do go through [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-svg-in-flutter-3dcf7b1dd713) article on medium and have a look through the flutter_svg [repo](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg). They are pretty active in resolving issues if you think something is broken.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

No by default but you can use this library

flutter_svg 0.17.4
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg
It works great

Answer (score 0):

It's safe, it just takes some extra work.  There are helper packages on: https://pub.dev/. Search svg.

Comment: what do you mean by extra work ? you say about randering or developer work ?

Comment: You need to import a package and use that packages syntax.  Choose a package on pub.dev and it will explain how to install and use. svg support does not come with flutter

Answer (score -1):

**flutter provided officially**
[here is package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29808894)

Comment: It's not official